# How to query whether a type models Struct?

Tags: c++, boost-hana

Given a type `T`, I'd like to know whether that type satisfies Boost.Hana's `Struct` concept. In other words, I would like to construct a metafunction `is_struct_v` such that for

```
struct foo_t { int x; }
BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(foo_t, x);
```

the following code compiles:

```
static_assert(is_struct_v<foo_t>);
```

whereas `is_struct_v<std::vector<int>>` should return false.

My guess was that hana's `is_valid` "function" is appropriate for this, however, I'm unable to bend the compiler to my will. Here is my attempt:

```
    #include <boost/hana.hpp>
    namespace hana = boost::hana;

    template <typename TypeTag>
    constexpr auto is_struct(TypeTag t) {
        auto has_members = hana::is_valid([](auto v)
            -> decltype((void)(boost::hana::members(hana::traits::declval(v))))
        {});

        return has_members(t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool is_struct_v = is_struct(boost::hana::type_c<T>);
```

This does return `true` for the `foo_t` case, but when I attempt to apply `is_struct_v` to `std::vector<int>`, I get the following error in clang (trunk):

```
static_assert failed due to requirement 'hana::Struct<S>::value'
```

UPDATE: I've solved my own problem; see answer below. That said, I would still appreciate an explanation of why the version which uses `hana::members` doesn't work. I find it odd that the `static_assert` triggers a compile time error because I thought `is_valid` is supposed to SFINAE that away. What am I missing?

Comment: `hana::members` is not SFINAE friendly, but you can just as easily use the concept `hana::Struct` as you pointed out. (I think it is because of compile-time performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was silly. It was only after posting that I realized I could use the error message to solve my problem! So `hana::Struct<foo_t>::value` is `true`, while `hana::Struct<std::vector<int>>` is `false`.